# Would restriction on iOS version by App lead to AppStore rejection?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

If I set my app restricted to a certain version of iOS(, say, the exact version of iOS when the app is reviewed) programmatically, would it be rejected by AppStore reviewer?

The scenario is that I need to control the risk that a newer version of iOS is potentially incompatible with the app, considering that the networking based methods are not always available or reliable, and that I must notice and force the users to upgrade the App to the latest version which is tested to be compatible with the latest version of iOS.

EDIT:

It seems that a runtime detect-and-notify strategy is better. Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: I cannot overstate how _bad_ an idea this is. iOS system versions are generally released to developers well in advance of public releases and all changes are well-documented. It would result in a terrible user experience if the app was needlessly disabled.

Comment: The reason to do this is not because I would like to, but I have no choice in order to abide some kinda risk-management standard, like effectiveness during an OS upgrade or so.

Comment: Effectiveness during an OS upgrade? Why would you aim explicitly to have an ineffective app because the user (rightly) updated to the latest OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to approach this. New versions of iOS *shouldn't* break your app if you've written them properly. I'm not sure what "Networking based methods" you have in mind.

What you should do is make sure that your app works against the pre-release versions of new iOS releases. If it doesn't, fix it and release an update. If your app is set up for it, you can notify users of the new version, or they will see it anyway through the app store.

With your method, even if you got it approved by apple, you'd *guarantee* that an iOS upgrade would break your app. Is that the experience you want to provide to your users?

Comment: My thinking was like your suggestion, but my manager's idea's like 'who guarantees that users have networks available in the right place at right time?'.

Comment: You keep mentioning networks, I'm not sure why? Do you mean that the user might not have networks available to download a new version of your app? If that's the case, they can't upgrade either...

Comment: Yes, they would be unable to upgrade then. But I need to assure they do not use the app in an unverified condition.

Comment: No, you really don't. No other apps on the store do this. Why do you need to?

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop an app from working *above* a version of the OS, but that shouldn't be a problem. As long as you're using public APIs and classes you shouldn't run into any (many) problems - **Apple enforce this for a reason!**

Can you explain what you mean by

> considering that the networking based methods are not always
>   available or reliable

Comment: If I used networking based methods, then there would be problems analyzing risks of networking based methods...

Comment: I've no idea what that means. What kind of risks are you thinking of? If you used UITableViews would you analyse the risk of UITableView methods each time the OS changed? Why are you so focused on "*networking methods*"?

Answer (score 1):

No - There's a section in developer.com which explains how to set your app to specific versions:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/15-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html

And when you say programatically - you probably don't want to do that, as users would get annoyed if they (pay and) download your app, and then find it does not work. Use the settings instead, so that it gets recognised on a download attempt.

Comment: Sorry, you have misunderstood my question. What I want is not only to support from a version of iOS, but also prohibit the app from working for any iOS above certain version, to force the users upgrade the app with new iOS.

Comment: why don't you just issue an update? Are you saying that you want to force them to purchase a _different_ app when a new OS version comes out?

Answer (score 1):

> considering that the networking based methods are not always available
>   or reliable

Not sure what you mean by this, Apple will not remove things that an App compiled against a particular version of iOS is depending on. If you assume network methods they will not vanish out from under you. They might become deprecated under future versions of iOS, but they won't disappear.

That said if you provide a web service call that your app makes at launch time you could supply it with the iOS version the app found and return a message to provide the user with a nudge to upgrade. I don't think Apple will mind this; also you could leave it off until the app goes live.